# PostgreSQL on Mac OSX - cannot log in as postgres user

Tags: macos, postgresql, geodjango, postgresql-9.1

I installed postgresql and geodjango on Mac OSX following this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#kyngchaos) word for word.
For some reason

```
sudo su - postgres
```

does not work. I put in my sudo password, but when I type "whoami" it's still my normal user login.

I know there is postgres user after I saw the list from

```
dscl . -list /Users UniqueID
```

Any idea why this is happening? I installed PSQL 9.1.1 server version.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of `grep postgres /etc/passwd`?

Comment: What is the output of `finger postgres`?

Comment: The output of 'finger postgres' is

Comment: Login: postgres                         Name: PostgreSQL Server
Directory: /var/empty                   Shell: /usr/bin/false
Never logged in.
No Mail.
No Plan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The postgres account probably has disabled login rights and/or /bin/false as the login shell.

In this case you had best invoke postgresql commands directly, eg: sudo -u postgres psql

That should work even with a disabled login shell.